# SQL Substring and Last index of

Tags: sql, sql-server

i've got stuck with substring.

On input i've got a string that looks like `Sometext (123456)`. Those digits at the end are random. I need to get only text from that string.

Comment: More examples. So you want "Sometext ()" out or "Sometext"? What if you have "Sometext(123ABC456&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;)"?

Comment: I have only digits inside the braces

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this?

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Val VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @Data VALUES ('Sometext (123456)')
INSERT @Data VALUES ('')
INSERT @Data VALUES (NULL)
INSERT @Data VALUES ('S(123456)')
INSERT @Data VALUES ('(123456)')

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(', Val) > 0 THEN 
            RTRIM(SUBSTRING(val,1, CHARINDEX('(', Val) - 1))
        ELSE Val
    END
FROM @Data
```

Answer (score 4):

If we want to remove the sentence and keep the number we might do like this.

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(MAX); 
SET @Text = 'Sometext (123456)'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX(' ', @Text) + 1, LEN(@Text)) As TextOutput
```

The result will be: (123456)

Answer (score 3):

It really does depend on the format of your input string, but here is a slightly different approach using [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx) that will return the string until it matches a non A-Z character:

```
declare @text varchar(500); set @text = 'Sometext (123456)'
select SUBSTRING(@text, 0, PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%' , @text))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first part up to the '(' you could try

```
declare @t varchar(50)
set @t = 'function (12343)'

select rtrim(substring(@t,1, charindex('(', @t)-1))
```